# Does the longest road need to have settlements/cities at endpoints?

Tags: catan

The questions is, in the following setup:

```
--S--S---C-
```

where `-` represents roads, `S` settlements, `C` cities, is the 'longest road' at 5, or 8?

I had originally thought 8, but as I read the FAQ:

> The Longest Road is a continuous road connecting two intersections, which consists of at least 5 individual road pieces and is not interrupted by game pieces belonging to other players. It has more individual road pieces than any other connecting road of this type.

I'm a bit unsure what is meant by *connecting road*.

I'm probably a bit hopeful that my original thought is incorrect, as I find it annoying when extra road segments are built, sometimes without even a possibility of a future settlement, for the hope of two points.

Comment: Related curiosity: would this stricter definition be better for the game?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is 8, the relevant rules are exactly what you quoted.

> The Longest Road is a continuous road **connecting two intersections**, which consists of at least 5 individual road pieces and is not interrupted by game pieces belonging to other players. It has more individual road pieces than any other connecting road of this type.

The bolded part tells you what "connecting road" refers to, in this case 2 intersections. It doesn't matter if they have settlements/cities or not.

Comment: Key to this is the definition of an intersection. It's the intersection of the hex pieces, not the intersection of the road with something else.